# Using PHP session_decode() without adding the session variables to own session

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP script that uses session_decode to get the session variables of customer's session (from session stored file).
The problem is that whenever I call the script and it reads the session variables, it also add them to my own session. Is there a way to avoid this or maybe use a better method to get the customer's session information without using session_decode?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK PHP uses the same algorithm to serialize its session data, as `serialize` function does (at least in default settings) – so `unserialize` should work on them as well. However, that you even have the need to read session data that is not connected to the current session leads to assume that there might be something wrong in your data model already … and that that data should have been stored elsewhere, f.e. a database, in the first place. (Unless this is only for some kind of live debugging purposes.)

Comment: @CBroe: I am using the osCommerce eCommerce framework, which has a script called who_online that shows online customers and their session variables, such as shopping cart details etc.
This comes with the framework by default and not a script I wrote myself. Is there a problem to have it this way?

Comment: @CBroe, I have just looked at http://us.php.net/session_decode and it says that unserialize is actually not the same, quote: "Please note the unserialization method is not the same as unserialize(). The serialization method is internal to PHP and can be set using session.serialize_handler."
Any other ideas?

Comment: _“[…] which has a script called who_online that shows online customers and their session variables”_ – well if that script provides that functionality already, what else do you need to implement yourself now? // You could maybe simply try and make a copy of $_SESSION, then set it to an empty array, use session_decode … and afterwards reverse the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the simplest solution/workaround:

```
<?php
// if session is not started
session_start();

// store our current session
$my_sess = $_SESSION;

// decode $data (the encoded session data, either from a file or database). Remember, decoded data is put directly into $_SESSION
session_decode($data);
$data = $_SESSION;

print_r($data);

// restore our own session
$_SESSION = $my_sess;

?>
```